# Task freezes on Return

Tags: python, celery

I've got a partially working Python Celery application, which is able to execute jobs on remote workers. Synchronization however is not working correctly all the times.

After some time spent in tracking down the problem, I realized it depends on the workers not returning. They are able to complete the task, but sometime they simply freeze while returning. While usually I can see the `Task ... succeeded in $time` message, in those case the message does not show up.

If I try sending a `SIGQUIT` (just with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd>), the worker keeps being frozen. I have to kill it with `SIGTERM`.

Any hint?

#### Side notes

No tasks calling tasks. Every task is called by the master process

The workflow is the following

```
async = bar.s(...) | baz.s(...)
# later on...
async.parent.get()
# later on...
async.get()
```

...but even executing `bar` and `baz` without using a chain the same effect persists. Results are not ignored by setting, and `ignore_result=True` is **not** specified anywhere. Indeed the system initially works fine, and then gets stuck.

The `celery inspect active` command returns the job specification itself on the blocked worker.

#### Current configuration

```
app = celery.Celery(
    broker='amqp://...'
    backend='amqp'
)

app.conf.update(
    CELERY_TASK_SERIALIZER='json',
    CELERY_RESULT_SERIALIZER='json',
    CELERY_ACCEPT_CONTENT=['json'],
    CELERY_TIMEZONE = 'UTC',
    CELERY_ENABLE_UTC = True,
    CELERY_RESULT_PERSISTENT = True,
    CELERY_TRACK_STARTED = True
)
```

Also the same happens by using Redis insead of RabbitMQ.

#### Log from workers:

Sometimes it can happen to have a *Broken Pipe* notification from *billiard*, but this seems not to be related, as it happens only sometimes.

```
[2014-11-25 10:47:20,995: DEBUG/MainProcess] | Worker: Starting Hub
[2014-11-25 10:47:20,996: DEBUG/MainProcess] ^-- substep ok
[2014-11-25 10:47:20,996: DEBUG/MainProcess] | Worker: Starting Pool
[2014-11-25 10:47:21,002: DEBUG/MainProcess] ^-- substep ok
[2014-11-25 10:47:21,004: DEBUG/MainProcess] | Worker: Starting Consumer
[2014-11-25 10:47:21,004: DEBUG/MainProcess] | Consumer: Starting Connection
[2014-11-25 10:47:22,053: INFO/MainProcess] Connected to redis://:**@...
[2014-11-25 10:47:22,053: DEBUG/MainProcess] ^-- substep ok
[2014-11-25 10:47:22,053: DEBUG/MainProcess] | Consumer: Starting Events
[2014-11-25 10:47:22,094: DEBUG/MainProcess] ^-- substep ok
[2014-11-25 10:47:22,094: DEBUG/MainProcess] | Consumer: Starting Mingle
[2014-11-25 10:47:22,095: INFO/MainProcess] mingle: searching for neighbors
[2014-11-25 10:47:23,152: INFO/MainProcess] mingle: all alone
[2014-11-25 10:47:23,152: DEBUG/MainProcess] ^-- substep ok
[2014-11-25 10:47:23,152: DEBUG/MainProcess] | Consumer: Starting Gossip
[2014-11-25 10:47:23,183: DEBUG/MainProcess] ^-- substep ok
[2014-11-25 10:47:23,184: DEBUG/MainProcess] | Consumer: Starting Tasks
[2014-11-25 10:47:23,193: DEBUG/MainProcess] ^-- substep ok
[2014-11-25 10:47:23,194: DEBUG/MainProcess] | Consumer: Starting Control
[2014-11-25 10:47:23,223: DEBUG/MainProcess] ^-- substep ok
[2014-11-25 10:47:23,223: DEBUG/MainProcess] | Consumer: Starting Heart
[2014-11-25 10:47:23,225: DEBUG/MainProcess] ^-- substep ok
[2014-11-25 10:47:23,225: DEBUG/MainProcess] | Consumer: Starting event loop
[2014-11-25 10:47:23,226: INFO/MainProcess] celery@... ready.
[2014-11-25 10:47:23,226: DEBUG/MainProcess] | Worker: Hub.register Pool...
[2014-11-25 10:47:23,227: DEBUG/MainProcess] basic.qos: prefetch_count->4
[2014-11-25 10:47:24,095: INFO/MainProcess] Received task: simulation.launch[76b59c23-9035-49b9-9997-fa9d6c347a76]
[2014-11-25 10:47:24,096: DEBUG/MainProcess] TaskPool: Apply <function _fast_trace_task at 0x26e6230> (args:(<all my args...
[2014-11-25 10:47:24,099: INFO/MainProcess] Received task: simulation.launch[13844d7b-90ad-427a-b7c0-4e5f4fd3aef0]
[2014-11-25 10:47:24,100: DEBUG/MainProcess] Task accepted: simulation.launch[76b59c23-9035-49b9-9997-fa9d6c347a76] pid:13997
[2014-11-25 10:47:24,102: INFO/MainProcess] Received task: simulation.launch[0e3a13ac-845e-47ab-b969-88931a7a4397]

<follows output of the task being executed. Then the task returns>

<silence for a long time>

[2014-11-25 10:54:32,244: ERROR/Worker-1] Pool process <Worker(Worker-1, started daemon)> error: OSError(32, 'Broken pipe')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/testing/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/billiard/pool.py", line 289, in run
    sys.exit(self.workloop(pid=pid))
  File "/home/testing/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/billiard/pool.py", line 373, in workloop
    put((READY, (job, i, (False, einfo), inqW_fd)))
OSError: [Errno 32] Broken pipe
```

Comment: can you post your celery worker logs?

Comment: post your sample task also. if you have set `ignore_result=True` then `get()` wont return even if task is completed

Comment: @ChillarAnand, not using ignore_result, now specified also in question. I'm posting logs as soon as available.

Comment: @ChillarAnand, I found a broken pipe error after waiting enough time...

Comment: Also I replaced celery with huey, and it works. I think this is very related to the celery configuration, at this point.

Comment: you are accepting only `json`. may be you have pickle issue somewhere in your tasks?

Comment: @ChillarAnand, I'm accepting only json. If it was a serialization problem, then *all* execution would not work.